# JAXB unmarshalling inXml flag to full object

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, xml-parsing, jaxb, xsd

I've got a following problem. My schema is as follows.

```
    <xs:element name="subject">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="subjectId" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:choice>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="inXml" type="xs:boolean"/>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="subjectId" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="names" type="Name" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

..... and so on.

which results in XML with 2 types of objects:

1. beautifully done nodes with all data i need (subjecId, names, etc. )
2. subjectId + inXml flag set to true.

While unmarshalling ofc I get either one of those.

How can I, during the unmarshalling process, make the app to look for the full data and replace it where needed?

Comment: Your question is very vague, but from the description it seems to be more of a problem with the scema and XML document *content* than with the unmarshalling. You have a `xs:choice` statement in the schema after all.

Comment: Well - the content of XML is optimized - that's why it contains that flag. What I need is to get data ( <subject> node) from my XML which is somewhere used.